# Converting my laptop to a desktop - removing the screen and the screen case

Tags: laptop

I've got an old laptop where the right hinge connecting the base and the screen came apart and destroyed the screen.  What I'd like to do is remove the screen and it's case entirely, and just boot to an external monitor (converting it into a desktop)

Do you see any issues with almost literally cutting off the top?  (it's a lenovo yoga 710)

Comment: Check for any wires that might be cut... keep the circuits in the top half of the case. Also, you'll need to extend the WiFi antenna if you put this in a metal case.

Answer (score 1):

The only cables that run through the screen are for the camera assembly, screen, and wifi antenna.

Rather than cutting it off, I would recommend taking the back cover off of the device and unplugging the cables running up to the screen.  This will make sure you don't damage the motherboard in the process.  If you want to use wifi in the future, make sure you keep the wifi antenna intact.